# Как я могу суммировать числа, которые я получил на выходе при помощи цикла while?

Tags: python

У меня есть задача:

> "Чем дольше разговариваешь - тем меньше платишь". За первую минуту
> разговора ты платишь 30 копеек, а за каждую следующую на 3 копейки
> меньше за предыдущую. Плата за 11 минуту и подальшие уже не
> считывается. Вопрос: сколько будет стоит абоненту оплата, если он
> будет разговаривать 10 минут?

Решил я эту часть с помощью вот такого вот когда:

```
i = 30
while i != 0:
    i = i - 3
    print(i)
```

Я узнал сколько я заплачу за каждую минуту разговора. Теперь я хочу суммировать все эти числа, полученные на выходе и узнать сколько мне обойдется в общем за 10 минут разговора. Я попробовал суммировать с помощью sum() вот таким образом:

```
i = 30
while i != 0:
    i = i - 3
    print(sum(i))
```

После чего получил ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\123\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 5, in
 <module>
     print(sum(i)) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Насколько я понял мне нужно эти числа упорядочить в каком-то списке, чтобы потом с помощью этой функции я смог их всех суммировать. Как это осуществить я ещё не понимаю, буду рад, если вы поможете мне найти выход. Я надеюсь, что обьяснил всё понятно.

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь. Узнал, усвоил, буду использовать в дальнейшем

Answer (score 0):

создайте переменную `total` и прибавляет туда каждый раз текущую стоимость

```
i = 30
total = 0

while i != 0:
    total += i
    i = i - 3
```

несколько советов: конструкцию `i = i - 3` лучше заменить на `i -= 3`.

Также если бы изначальная стоимость была бы, к примеру, `29`, то ваш цикл стал бы бесконечным. поэтому надо проверить что `i` положительный:

```
i = 30
total = 0

while i > 0:
    total += i
    i -= 3
```

Если же вам охото использовать список то вот:

```
i = 30 
arr = []          # создаём пустой список

while i > 0:
    arr.append(i) # добавляем элемент в конец 
    i -= 3

print(arr)        # выводим список
print(sum(arr))   # находим сумму
```

Comment: Спасибо за такое обширное объяснение в двух вариантах, в том числе и про то, что, если взять число 29, то будет бессконечный цикл. Вроде такая деталь, а я и не заметил.

Comment: @Delarosa [что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Можно положить все элементы в список и после цикла, с помощью функции **sum** вывести значение

```
i = 30
ilist = []
while i != 0:
    ilist.append(i)
    i = i - 3

print(sum(ilist))
```